# Nested GestureDetector OnTap Functions

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have nested `GestureDetetor`s but problem is that only the child `GestureDetector`'s `onTap` is executed. I do not wish to override the child's onTap, rather, I want both the parent's and the child's onTap to execute. Here's my code:

```
    GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            todo1(); 
        },
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                todo2();
            },
            child: Text("Nested Gesture")))
```

How do I change this to call both `todo1()` and `todo2()` onTap?

edit: the child is a re-usable custom widget that has its own implementation but is now being used by the parent which also has an implementation of its own in addition to its child

Comment: This, for me, makes no sense. You added two nested getsture detectors just to call two different methods ? why not calling both of them from the same ```onTap() ```.

Comment: @danypata - i understand where that comes from, but in my case the child is a re-usable custom widget that has its own implementation but is now being used by the parent which also has an implementation of its own in addition to its child.

Answer (score 4):

I made a quick custom gesture recognizer - it cancels the gesture only if user has moved too far from the initial tap point.

Usage example:

```dart
UniversalTapHandler(
  onTap: () {
    print("Tap 1");
  },
  child: UniversalTapHandler(
    onTap: () {
      print("Tap 2");
    },
    child: Text("Nested Gesture"),
  )
)
```

Source code:

```dart
class UniversalTapHandler extends RawGestureDetector {
  UniversalTapHandler({
    @required GestureTapCallback onTap,
    @required Widget child,
  }):
    super(
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
        _UniversalPointerHandler: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<_UniversalPointerHandler>(
          () => _UniversalPointerHandler(onTap: onTap),
          (_) {},
        ),
      },
      child: child,
    );
}

class _UniversalPointerHandler extends OneSequenceGestureRecognizer {
  _UniversalPointerHandler({
    @required this.onTap,
  }): super();

  final GestureTapCallback onTap;

  final _maxDistance = 18; // as in official recognizer by default
  Offset _startPosition;

  void _reset() {
    _startPosition = null;
  }

  @override
  void addPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    _startPosition = event.position;
    startTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
    resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    if (event is PointerUpEvent) {
      stopTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
      if (_startPosition != null) {
        onTap();
      }
    }
    if (event is PointerMoveEvent && _startPosition != null) {
      if ((event.position - _startPosition).distance > _maxDistance) {
        rejectGesture(event.pointer);
        _reset();
      }
    }
    if (event is PointerCancelEvent || event is PointerExitEvent || event is PointerRemovedEvent) {
      _reset();
    }
  }

  @override
  void resolve(GestureDisposition disposition) {
    if (disposition == GestureDisposition.rejected) {
      _reset();
    }
    super.resolve(disposition);
  }

  @override
  void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {}

  @override
  String get debugDescription => "_UniversalPointerHandler: Custom Gesture Recognizer";
}
```

**UPDATE**
Don't forget to import this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the parent’s and child’s onTap methods to execute, you can use the following code snippet:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // parent onTap method
  },
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      // child onTap method
    },
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    child: Container(),
  ),
);
```

The behavior property is set to `HitTestBehavior.translucent`, which allows both the parent and child widgets to receive taps.

Answer (score -1):

You can call todo1() in the nested onTap callback:

```dart
  GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            todo1(); 
        },
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                todo2();
                todo1();
            },
            child: Text("Nested Gesture")))
```

Comment: Ofcourse I will repeat code inside widget tree..